# loop_shop_columns filter not working properly (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce Filter **loop_shop_columns** not working properly in Woocommerce version 2.6.1

I am using the below code:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {

    function loop_columns() {
    return 3; // 3 products per row
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try write it on top file: WooCommerce > Loop > loop-start.php

Answer (score 1):

If you look the woocommerce core function wc_get_loop_class in woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php you will find this row:

```
$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = max( 1, ! empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) ? $woocommerce_loop['columns'] : apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 ) );
```

So if $woocommerce_loop['columns'] is not empty and not lower than 1 at this point of the process, your filter will never be taken, and I suppose this is the case.

To be honest I haven't investigated more, however as solution I propose:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'my_woo_modify_product_class',40,3 );
function my_woo_modify_product_class( $classes, $class = '', $post_id = '' ) {
    if ( ! $post_id || ! in_array( get_post_type( $post_id ), array( 'product', 'product_variation' ) ) ) {
        return $classes;
    }
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    if ( $product ) {
        if ( $index = array_search( 'first', $classes ) ) {
            unset( $classes[ $index ] );
        }
        if ( $index = array_search( 'last', $classes ) ) {
            unset( $classes[ $index ] );
        }   
        global $woocommerce_loop;
        $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = ! empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) ? $woocommerce_loop['loop'] + 1   : 1;
        $loop = 1 + absint( ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 )/2 );
        $cols = 4;
        if ( 0 === ( $loop - 1 ) % $cols || 1 === $cols ) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        } elseif ( 0 === $loop % $cols ) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

where $cols is the the desired number of columns
This filter unset 'first' and 'last' classes that cause the 2 columns layout and introduce them again taking in account of the $cols value.
$woocommerce_loop['loop'] is a global Woocommerce variable that for each product item assumes the values 1,3,5,.... In any case I've tested and it works with WooCommerce 3.0.7. Then you should still adjust the product witdh with css.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css as well.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
.archive ul.products li.product ,.shop_page ul.products li.product { 
            width: 21% !important;
            margin: 2% !important;
            clear: none !important;
}
.archive ul.products li.product:nth-child(4n+1),.shop_page ul.products li.product:nth-child(4n+1) {
            clear: both !important;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set Priority to 1.

```
    add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns',1,10);

if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 4; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```